# NestJs | Set max header size

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

I am implementing API in NestJs and new to this framework. For one of my API I am getting error as

```
Status Code: 431 Request Header Fields Too Large
```

To fix this issue I want to change max header size in NestJs configuration. Where do I change this configuration in NestJs application.

Answer (score 1):

This question is already answered for node [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63319913/nestjs-request-header-size-error-http-code-431) and for nest you can pass the argument as same as for node:

```
nest start -- --max-http-header-size=80000
```

As it's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140234/setting-request-header-size-limit-in-nest-js)

NestJS is a framework for NodeJS, you can pass NodeJS params directly, so I think this could be useful for you [NodeJS command line options](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_max_http_header_size_size)

And in case you want to set it from the code you can follow the same idea as [this post explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049993/node-js-how-to-limit-the-http-request-size-and-upload-file-size) something bodyparser is available for both.

I hope this is useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I could not get this to work by forwarding the node argument the way it's done in the currently accepted answer. Perhaps this is specific to my environment, but I was able to get it working using Nest's `exec` argument:

`nest start --exec "node --max-http-header-size=40960"`

The official description of the `exec` argument:

> Binary to run (default: node).

https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/usages#nest-start