# Setting request header size limit in nest.js

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I am getting this attached error ([Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rm2A7.png))
while trying to set the request header size limit in nest.js.
error: unknown option '--max-http-header-size'
This must be a working case when directly running express/node.
How can I make it work in nestjs, since the default header size is set to 8 KB?

Comment: See this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14340

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the argument through `--`:

```
nest start -- --max-http-header-size=80000
```

Comment: @Ananya Gulati: any feedback?